# discord.js - Removing role from player - Error

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a player table and if the player has is_deleted 1, the role should be removed from him, which I do with the code below, which doesn't seem to be working, so my question is: What's this error about?

Error

```
member.roles.remove(role);
       ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')
```

Code

```
conec.query("SELECT players.user_discord_id, teams.discord_group_id FROM players RIGHT JOIN teams ON players.team_id=teams.id WHERE players.is_deleted=1", async function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
        
    for (const item of result) {
        user = item.user_discord_id;
        role = item.discord_group_id;

        guild = client.guilds.cache.get(targetGuild);
        member = guild.members.cache.get(user);

        member.roles.remove(role);
        console.log("removed role " + role + " from " + user);
        }
    })
```

Comment: How do you store `user_discord_id` and `discord_group_id`? As strings or as numbers?

Comment: `user_discord_id` is the full tag -> e.g. Name#1234 -> which is stored as a `varchar` so a String.

the `discord_group_id` is also stored as a `varchar` so a String

Comment: Oh, I see, so it's not really a user's ID but their tag. You should store their ID instead. If you can't change it, you can fetch all members and iterate over them to find the one with the tag you saved in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that the 'member' variable has a null value. So you cannot access a property of a null value.

Try change

```
member = guild.members.cache.get(user);
```

To

```
member = await guild.members.fetch(user);
```

Maybe the user doesn't exist in your cache or you're not expecting the function to return the data.